# www subdomain points to a completely different project

Tags: http, heroku, dns

I have the weirdest problem. I deployed my app to heroku and registered a domain name lets say: `xyz.example` . I tried to move to this URL and my project was there and working fine, then I tried to move to `www.xyz.example` and I get a completely different project that exist in my computer but have nothing to do with heroku and never have been deployed to there! Its a static website that has been uploaded to another domain using filezila a while ago. My domain provider is Domain.com. I tried to look there for answer in my domains list but nothing has changed and it's all looks fine. What can it be?

Comment: Is there a(n A) record for www.xyz.com at Domain.com? If not does the www subdomain resolve to 127.0.0.1 by default (with nslookup)?

Answer (score 0):

To connect your heroku hosting to your domain name,
you have to open your domain name account and in the DNS Management page add in the cname the host: `www` and in the point to: your heroku url And in the heroku page in the settings add three domains:

1. `*.xyz.example`
2. `xyz.example`
3. `www.xyz.example`

This should work :) Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&feature=youtu.be